# Can't calibrate my touchscreen (Lubuntu)

Tags: lubuntu, touchscreen, monitor-calibration

So I'm making a sort of music player with some old hardware and before it was put on hold my (opinion) question helped me to choose Lubuntu as the OS.  It looked like my touch screen would probably work since someone had solved the issue.  So I proceeded and I'm happy except for one thing.  That method to get the touch screen functional isn't working for me.

When I got the hardware together and Lubuntu loaded on, the touch screen worked except where I touched wasn't where it reacted.  The idea was to use `xinput_calibrator` to calibrate the screen, which was supposed to work, but then enter some of the archaic code Linux uses, to make the setting permanent.  Unfortunately calibrating the screen made it stop working altogether.  Because I didn't make the change permanent, it functions again when I reboot, but it's still useless and all of my internet searches come up with the same solution.  Use `xinput_calibrator`; make it permanent.

As you might have noticed, I'm not really a Linux user so if you have any suggestions, I would appreciate it if you keep it on a 4th grade level.

I hope someone can help, otherwise I might need to look into a different distro and start all over again or worse, switch back to Windows!

Here's my hardware:

Lilliput 629GL-70NP/C/T touchscreen monitor
Asus AT3GC-I motherboard
2 GB RAM (max'd)
Onboard video
Onboard sound
Kingston 128 GB SSD

Thank you!